# Problem iterating over JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the JSON:

```
{
    "GetCommentsByPostResult": [
        {
            "CommentCreated": "\\/Date(1305736030505+0100)\\/",
            "CommentText": "Comment 1"
        },
        {
            "CommentCreated": "\\/Date(1305736030505+0100)\\/",
            "CommentText": "Comment 2"
        },
        {
            "CommentCreated": "\\/Date(1305736030505+0100)\\/",
            "CommentText": "Comment 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

And Im trying to iterate over it using this:

```
$.each(data.GetCommentsByPostResult, function (e) {
                        alert(e.CommentText);
                    });
```

But all im getting is 3 alert screens with 'undefined' in it....no idea why anyone know?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the first parameter in [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)'s callback (when called on an array) is the index in to the array.

This should work:

```
$.each(data.GetCommentsByPostResult, function(index, element) {
    alert(element.CommentText);
});
```

Comment: amazing, should have read the documentation a bit more closely but yeah ok still learning :-) will tick as answer